# Why can interleaving make the channel "memoryless"?

Tags: digital-communications, noise, channelcoding

I'm trying to understand "interleaving" from a theoretical point of view. [This paper](http://web.mit.edu/6.441/www/reading/IT-V35-N6.pdf) claimed that by sufficient long interleaving, the channel can be treated as memoryless.

Does this holds for all memory noise, no matter if it's stationary/non-stationary or ergodic/non-ergodic?

Is there mathematical proof for this memoryless property?

Comment: The claim is for practical/structured coding schemes, as the MIT paper ("efficient coding techniques for memoryless channels may be used", "the interleaving process, being invertible, does not remove the channel memory but only transfers it into a latent fragmented form which does not interfere with the operation of standard error correcting coders and decoders") and DilipSarwate's comment pointed out.

Comment: If you are interested in random coding achieving channel capacity, there is always a scheme. But, as the paper did say, the capacity of channel+interleavers is less than (or equal, but generally not) the capacity of the very channel alone. The proof for this is [Data processing inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality). For the question of how to quantify these capacities, you need to assume several assumptions, most importantly of codeblock length and the distribution that model the channel.

Comment: ... The classic proxy for this approach is [error exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_exponent), which is also talked about in the MIT paper. Recently, an alternative is [finite blocklength theory](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/ESIT-Tutorial-YP.pdf). For more details, I would suggest you start with the survey of [this dissertation](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/thesis.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[Posted as an answer because it is too long to be left as a comment]

It is *not* the case that a channel with memory can *always* be treated as a memoryless channel with sufficiently long interleaving. If the channel has infinite memory (e.g. the impulse response dies away exponentially), then no amount of interleaving will make the channel appear memoryless, though as a practical matter, interleaving to a depth of 5 or 6 time-constants will work reasonably well to ameliorate the inter-symbol interference.  But, as the OP's reference points out, the capacity of the channel when interleaving is used is smaller than the capacity without interleaving if only the memory and ISI were used constructively to improve performance instead of being treated as nuisances to be eliminated if possible.

Comment: I'm in fact more on the informaiton theory/Shannon theory side where we care about the existence of the coding scheme asymtotically achieving the capacity instead of if the scheme is practical..Is there any theoretical analysis of this memoryless behaviour? Thank you!

Comment: @hzxscyq in that case, why do you even concern yourself with interleaving? Your "asymptotically achieving" refers to codes of codes whose length approaches infinity. For that regime, interleaving does absolutely nothing. Can you explain what you need an analysis for? Interleaving is just permutation, thus the mutual information over a channel is completely invariant to it, if we're talking about asymptotically infinite code lengths.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm confusing about the arugment in paragraphs above Eq. (33) , Page 8 in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1003844), where the auther treated a channel with additive ergodic noise as a channel with i.i.d. noise by 'interleaving argument'.